# Subset data frame and preserve row and column names

Tags: r, performance, subset, bioinformatics, correlation

I have a 71521 row X 894 column data frame that contains correlation values (-1.0 to +1.0). The row names are gene names while the column names are miRNA names.

I would like to create a sub data frame (or matrix, doesn't matter) that contains only correlation values that are: 
1) between -1.0 and -0.9 (negative corr)
2) between +0.9 and +1.0 (positive corr)
3) between -0.05 and +0.05 (no correlation)

I used `which()` function and found out there are 4,120 negative corr, 380,132 positive corr, and 11,360,858 non corr values in my data frame.

I would like to create a subset data frame that contains those correlation scores AND preserves the corresponding row and column names for identification of the miRNA-mRNA relationship corresponding to that score.

Basically, a data frame or matrix containing 3 columns: miRNA_name ; mRNA_name ; Corr_Score

I have tried writing nested `for loop`s, but I was wondering if anyone knows of a more efficient way. Perhaps some combination of `apply` and/or `data.tables`?

Comment: Can you show some data? Use head() to slice your data frame. For your problem subset() or aggregate() may help.

Comment: "Create a sub data frame..." based in three conditions. Does that mean you one three sub data frames, or just 1 which combines the three conditions?

Comment: @jlhoward - Either way would work.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like a good time to pull out sparse matrices, and we can multiply by abs(x) > 9 to zero out all the small elements:

```
require(Matrix)
x <- matrix(runif(100), 10,10)
x <- Matrix(x * (abs(x) > .9), sparse=TRUE)
summary(x)
#10 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix", with 14 entries
#    i  j            x
#1   3  1 0.9997396283
#2   8  1 0.9832526373
#3   5  2 0.9220406844
#4   8  2 0.9317862403
#5   6  3 0.9242458937
#6   3  5 0.9451522273
#7   6  5 0.9262013000
#8   4  6 0.9731352150
#9   5  6 0.9259489737
#10  8  8 0.9011057722
#11  1  9 0.9068403998
#12  8  9 0.9979463725
#13 10  9 0.9965988533
#14  3 10 0.9191754723
```

Answer (score 2):

The data sounds like it should be a matrix

```
set.seed(123)
m = matrix(runif(26*26, -1, 1), nrow=26, dimnames=list(letters, LETTERS))
```

coerce it to a 'long' data.frame

```
df = data.frame(Row=rownames(m)[row(m)], Col=colnames(m)[col(m)], 
                Value=as.vector(m))
```

and subset as desired

```
df[df$Value > 0.9,]
```

so

```
> head(df[df$Value > 0.9,])
    Row Col     Value
11    k   A 0.9136667
20    t   A 0.9090073
24    x   A 0.9885396
31    e   B 0.9260485
87    i   D 0.9699140
104   z   D 0.9089477
```

use logical expressions if you mean >0.9 OR < -0.9, etc.

```
df[df$Value > 0.9 | df$Value < -0.9,]
```

Comment: ^Martin Morgan comes through again! Like I said above, another R ninja comes through. Thanks again! Youve helped me before, and there is a good chance you will see another one of my questions in the future ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, a data frame or matrix containg 3 columns: miRNA_name ; mRNA_name ; Corr_Score

You could use `melt`:

```
cor(longley, method = "spearman")
melt(cor(longley, method = "spearman"))
```

And then do the subsetting...

Comment: Subsetting? I read up on the 'melt()' function. It seems like it just separates into individual rows. How does that help?

Comment: melt brings you data.frame to the long-format. Then you can extract correlations > 0.9. Pretty like @Martin Morgans answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like *within()* or *subset()* may help you:

```
data = data.frame(correl = runif(100, -1, 1), y = rnorm(100), z = sample(letters, 100, TRUE))

data = within(data, {
      label = ifelse(correl > -1.0 & correl < -0.9, 'Neg', ifelse(correl > 0.9 & correl < 1.0, 'Pos', 'None'))  
})

data = subset(data, label != 'None')

require(reshape2)
data2 = melt(data, id = 'label')

print(data2)
```

The rows are classified then stacked according to 'label'. You can change the 'id' parameter
depending on what you need.

PS: It seems you're missing the condition when correl is between -0.9 and 0.9.

Comment: Thanks! Im still not sure how to implement this on my data frame. The data frame you created only has 3 columns to start with. Mine has 894. I want to turn it into a 3-column data frame.